# EF: Best/Quickest way to update field by Id

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Currently, a database-record from the get loaded into a simplified model, which also stores the ID-key. After some computations, the one or more fields of the original record needs to be updated.

The Model is quite large (alot of strings) and the entrycount is likely to be > 100.000 entries per table. So loading them into memory results into a OutOfMemoryException.

```
class Model // Database-Table
{
    public Int Id { get; set; }
    public int Field { get; set; }
}

class SimpleModel
{
    int Id;
    int Field;
}

void Update( SimpleModel[] simpleModels )
{
    using( var ctx = new DbContext() )
    {
        foreach( var simpleModel in simpleModels )
        {
            var entry = ctx.ModelTable
                .Where( x => x.Id == simpleModel.Id )
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if( entry == null )
                continue;

            ctx.ModelTable.Attach( entry );

            entry.Field = simpleModel.Field;
        }

        if( ctx.ChangeTracker.HasChanges() )
            ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

However, this is painfully slow. Is there a way to speed this up, using the EntityFramework (without direct string-sql-queries)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you are using `FirstOrDefault()` you run new database query. You can load all entities in one query instead:

```
var ids = simpleModels.Select(sm => sm.Id);
var entries = ctx.ModelTable.Where(m => ids.Contains(m.Id)).ToList();
// or
var entriesById = ctx.ModelTable.Where(m => ids.Contains(m.Id)).ToDictionary(x => x.Id);
```

Then you can work with loaded entries in memory without additional database queries. E.g.

```
 foreach( var simpleModel in simpleModels )
 {
      Model entry;
      if (!entriesById.TryGetValue(simpleModel.Id, out entry))
         continue;

      entry.Field = simpleModel.Field;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. But this doesn't work on larger sets (>100k entries). How do I avoid a OutOfMemoryException? Do I have to manually batch them? I have updated my question and mentioned this there

Comment: I like your approach, instead of doing a lot of interactions with database for each row, we only make two calls to the database, one for reading the data and one for upating it, it's like SQL BulkUpdate

Comment: @user5997884 I would go with manual batching. All you need to do is repeat same load-update scenario for parts of `ids` array. You can go by 1000 for example.

Comment: @user5997884 you can do it using chunks, you do the updates every 1000 rows, and yes for 100k you are going to have memory exception, because the whole data is going to be loaded in the RAM

Comment: +1 for sergey, on top of that, do it in batches of say 1000 - 10 000, do some testing to see what number works best. Personally i don't get the point of checking or "skipping" if the result always exist. so it should just be `entry.Field = simpleModel.Field:`

Comment: @Seabizkit How do you ensure then, if the record still exists in the database?

Comment: @user5997884 your looking over records you just fetched... right? they always exist...

Comment: @Seabizkit not quite, im looking over results I fetched a while ago, processed some data, and want to write back. I cannot be sure some other process hasn't deleted the original record.

Comment: @user5997884 fair enough.. it might be a while ago, but you will be looping over the returned ones not the original list. so unless they are deleted within that transaction time you should be OK, update 1000 records, sub 2 secs to finish. also i don't think the entitybyId, actually does a DB check, just an FYI